# I create JButton loop with Array, but it's doesn't work

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i want to create button by loop as

- 1 2 3
- 4 5 6
- 7 8 9

but button have array2D when i write code is

```
private JButton cells[][];

// Constructor
public SliderGameFrame() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    this.add(panel);
    for (int i = 1; i <= cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= cells.length; j++) {
            cells[i][j] = new JButton(" " + i);
            panel.add(cells[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

it's doesn't work and error massage is *java.lang.NullPointerException*

Comment: You never iniztialize your Array.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= cells.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= cells.length; j++) {
```

into:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
```

Two-dimensional array's indices start from 0 to dimension-1.

Comment: it's doesn't work same ):

Comment: oh god, Im sorry to told that I forgot to iniztialize Array.

Comment: Well, even tough you forgot to initialize the array, your loops should be as I showed in the answer. It won't work otherwise.